# EGit SSH Exception caught during execution of ls-remote command

Tags: git, egit

I set up a GIT Server in our internal network. I can push to it using git://...../ and with the option `--enable=receive-pack` on the server.

But when I try to push via ssh using EGIT Eclipse plugin(ssh://username@ip_adress:22/project.git) I get the following error:

> Transport Error Cannot get remote repository refs.
>
> Reason:  Exception caught during execution of ls-remote command.

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Comment: What version of Eclipse and of EGit are you using. what is your platform (Windows? Linux), and what is its version?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 32bit, sp1. Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 (EE IDE). Egit 1.3.0.210202151440-r

Comment: Please try with a newer version of EGit from the nightly update site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly

Comment: egit ve4rsion 2.0.0 - same error

Comment: Does you private SSH key has a password attached to it?

Comment: I did some test but nothing worked. In my auth.log on the ssh server I see "May 14 13:57:13 server sshd[2015]: Accepted password for user from 10.80.3.88 port 51285 ssh2" And my ppk does not have a password

Comment: The git server is in our LAN and i removed all proxy setting from eclipse

Comment: one of the bugs making me crazy :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git://` and `ssh://` use different protocols (see [EGit User_Guide#Git_URLs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Git_URLs)). So either use the former in EGit too or make sure ssh access works.

Answer (score 0):

This problem's usually caused by problems in authentication which can happen if you're not authenticating as the git user, if you're using gitolite as the git user but using a key that's used for another account, or any other of a number of issues in authentication. You can fix this by generating a new keypair, posting the new public key, and authenticating using the new private key and the git user.

I posted more detailed instructions at [git, gitolite error push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283947/git-gitolite-error-push/11701630#11701630) (go there to avoid double posting/double editing.)