# Gitolite bug when pushing to server

Tags: linux, git, gitolite

I have a Linux server with Git and Gitolite. Until now, always works fine, but since yesterday I have a problem. I can connect and pull my repos but when I push I have these types of errors :

```
remote: Empty compile time value given to use lib at hooks/update line 6
remote: Use of uninitialized value in require at hooks/update line 7.
remote: Can't locate Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm in @INC (@INC contains:  /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at hooks/update line 7.
remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hooks/update line 7.
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To git@myhost.com:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@myhost.com:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git'
```

I'm lost... Can you help me please ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "[Empty compile time value](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#common-errors)" is typical of an url which bypasses gitolite.

You used:

```
git@myhost.com:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
```

But you should have used:

```
git@myhost.com:gitolite-admin
```

See "[git, gitolite error push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10283947/6309)" for more.

Comment: Yes but when I use git@myhost.com:gitolite-admin I have an error. Git say me that the repository gitolite-admin doesn't exist...

Comment: @Bob that means your installation isn't properly done: `ssh git@myhost.com` should return a gitolite message. Re-do your installation, making sure the `gitolite` script is in the `PATH` as exposed by your `sshd` on `myhost.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue was with cloning the repository using "http uri" of repo. If so following solution may resolve the issue.

edit `.git/config` that exists in project's root directory. 
Look for remote origin section.

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = http://myhost.com/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
```

Then replace url field in the config file with ssh url `git@myhost.com:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`

Then try to push.